# lightswitch html client failed to convert circular structure to json

Tags: json, visual-studio-lightswitch

Im trying to insert new data into the DB when a user scans a barcode into a field. When I hit save on the screen it says fail to convert circular structure to json.

```
      var report = myapp.activeDataWorkspace.BlanccoData.BMCReports.addNew();
        report.c_Date = Date.now();
        report.IsScannedReport = true;
        if (contentItem.screen.ScanSSN == true) {
            report.SSN = contentItem.value;
        }
var system = myapp.activeDataWorkspace.BlanccoData.BMCSystemInfo.addNew();
       // system.Report = report;

        system.Barcode = contentItem.screen.Barcode;
```

I think the commented line is throwing the exception but I need to reference it.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that you may have a circular relationship in your database?  That is reflected in your DataSource?

Comment: the database was provided to me from a company so I cant modify it. I am not really familiar with circular relationships and dont know how to over come it.

Comment: I have a report table and a system table a system must have a report and a report can have many systems

Comment: That sounds like a single 1 to many join.  When you produce JSON with data that has circular references it is possible for the result to be infinite, so it fails.  Not entirely sure what's causing your problem exactly, if you can't fix the data structure, you may need a different approach, like SQL or a Stored Proc.

Comment: see when I scan a barcode it produces a new row in the db but then when I hit save on the screen it produces that error

Comment: i think i need to change the relationship from one to many to many to one. Not sure how I can do that in lightswitch since its an external datasource

Comment: You need to change it in the SQL server then right click the data source and choose update data source.

Comment: im trying to get an exception thrown when debugging but nothing gets thrown.

Comment: if I just insert one table for example the report data and not the system data it will save fine

Comment: Go to Visual Studio -> Debug -> Exceptions -> JavaScript Runtime.

Comment: I am able to add it in the silverlight version using c# I created a test button